# How to make shuffle of the string and include data from second file?

Tags: php, shuffle

I have 2 txt files, one with questions:

```
1|question 1
2|question 2
...
```

second with answers^

```
1|1|answer 1 to q1
2|1|answer 2 to q1
3|2|answer 1 to q2
4|2|answer 2 to q2
...
```

And script, that output the questions:

```
function getTable($path_q,$path_a)
{
    $qOpen=file($path_q);
    $aOpen=file($path_a);
    $strResult='<div id="test">';
    for($i=0;$i<=sizeof($qOpen);$i++)
    {
        $masStr[$i]=explode('"',trim($qOpen[$i]));
        $masStrClear[$i] = array();
        foreach($masStr[$i] as $v)
        {
            if (!empty($v))
            {
                $masStrClear[$i][]=trim($v);
            }
        }
        for($j=0;$j<sizeof($masStrClear[$i]);$j++)
        {
            $question=explode('|',$masStrClear[$i][$j]);
            $strResult.='<span id="q'.$question[0].'"><h4>'.$question[1].'?</h4></span>';
        }
    }
    echo $strResult.'</div>';
}
getTable('data/test_1_q.txt','data/test_1_a.txt');
```

I want to add:

1) Shuffle function to all questions. `shuffle($masStr[$i])` doesn't work.

2) output answers by appropriate questions.
Help please!

Answer (score 2):

The reason your shuffle call isn't working is your fields are delimited by `|` characters, but you're exploding on `"`. There's no `"` in those lines of text, so explode returns a single string inside a single element array - shuffling a 1 element array is rather pointless.

Comment: I need the shuffle lines, not first id. I'm add `;` to end of the strings, and change explode to `$masStr[$i]=explode(';',trim($qOpen[$i]));`. But shuffle not work(